# Are there any hunters from Supernatural who haven't faced a personal tragedy?

Tags: supernatural

The Winchesters lost a mother/wife and one of them a fiance to a demon, Bobby Singer's wife to a demon possession, and Gorden's sister was turned into a vampire.

Are there any hunters (excluding Ghostfacers) who haven't lost someone to a supernatural tragedy?

Comment: Are you asking, no personal tragedy _at all_, or no personal tragedy before they became hunters?

Comment: No tradgedy that forced them into hunting.

Comment: What about Garth?

Comment: @ForceFlow "Garth Fitzgerald IV is a hunter. He went to college and dental school, becoming a dentist for awhile until he got his first case in which he claims he killed the Tooth Fairy." ~[Garth on Supernatural wiki](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Garth)

Comment: (SPOILER) In the final episode of "Supernatural", we get a montage glimpse of Sam Winchester's son.  The glimpses show he had a pretty nice upbringing with a caring father.  On Sam's death bed, we see the grown lad has a mystic tattoo like his old man. I'd infer that he therefore qualifies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mary Winchester fits the criteria, while Ellen Harvelle and Mary's parents (Samuel Campbell and Deanna Campbell) are possible candidates.

**[Mary Winchester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Winchester#Mary_Winchester)**

Mary was born into hunting, following in the footsteps - and being trained by - her parents.  Samuel even mentioned telling her about the Colt as a bedtime story.

**[Ellen Harvelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellen_Harvelle), [Samuel Campbell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Winchester#Samuel_Campbell) and Deanna Campbell**

I don't recall Ellen ever talking about why she started hunting, nor can I find anything about her motivations on the various wikis. Same for Samuel and Deanna.

Answer (score 4):

There's one and only one that I can think of, Eliot Ness. When Dean asked him who died and made him a hunter, he answered nobody, he "got the bug" when vampires were turning people in Cleveland.

Comment: Can you specify the episode in which the events you describe happen ?

Comment: The episode with Eliot Ness is "Time After Time" - Season 7, Episode 12

Answer (score 1):

There is Elliot Ness, obviously, and in season 11 there was Jesse's boyfriend, he just helped Jesse but he didn't have his own personal tragedy.

Comment: Could you add more detail? Episode numbers, quotes?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the hunter Asa Fox from Season 12 would count. Although he was rescued by Mary Winchester from a werewolf when he was just a kid, he did not experience any personal losses that I am aware of.